# Why does Weierstrass theorem does not apply to lower semicontinuity functions?

Tags: real-analysis

What is a counter example of a function that is lower semicontinuous on a bounded, closed interval $[a,b]$ but has no maximizer on this interval?

Answer (score 1):

On $[a,b]=[0,1]$, consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & 0 \le x < 1/2 \\ 0, & x\ge 1/2. \end{cases}$$
The supremum is $1/2$ but is not attained.